# Java JDK 7u4 64 Bit Install Not Launching

Tags: java, windows-7, jdk

I have downloaded the Java JDK 7u4 64 bit installer exe from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html

When I go to run it the UAC comes up and when I select yes, the UAC goes but then nothing else happens. There are no error messages and from what I have seen no processes have been made.

I am using Win 7 Ultimate 64 Bit SP1, I already have the JRE 7 64 bit as well as the JRE 6 32 bit (accidentally installed that first).

Thank you in advance,

Wolf

EDIT: Workaround found, check below for answer.

Comment: Don't ask side-questions.  Ask separate questions.

Comment: sorry, side question will be removed. I will check out Superuser thank you.

Comment: do you have admin rights?

Comment: yes, I run as administrator and still, nothing happens. I've also tried un-installing all JREs as well; to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Workaround found here (user6112349's post): https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10153715#10153715

1) goto c:\Users[your user]

2) create jdk1.7.0_04_combo directory

3) right click on folder and select permissions

4) click advanced button

5) deny delete/delete sub for each listed role/user

6) run downloader installer

7) goto jdk1.7.0_04 and run the java_jdk.exe (no need to copy to another dir)

Update number was changed but otherwise this is the same as his posted workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Combo' directory at step 2?